# How to download REST API response file?

Tags: java, rest, api, https

I have an API with these details:

```
GET /REST/sql_snapshot/2003-03-01.sql.gz
HTTP/1.1 Host: api.application.cap.cams.net
Authorization: Basic asdwqfasft

The response from API shown below omits the message body, which contains binary compressed SQL data.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2003 10:19:46 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.22 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I have this snippet of code initially

```
URL location = new URL("https://api.application.cap.cams.net/REST/sql_snapshot/2003-03-01.sql.gz");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) location.openConnection();
connection.setHostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifierFactory getHostnameVerifier());
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConfigurerFactory.getConfigurer().getSSLSocketFactory());
connection.connect();
// after this I will retrieve the input stream of the connection. Then write the file (zip file).
```

Am I doing something wrong because I'm not able to get the input stream since the response code of the connection is -1. I know this response code but I'm not entirely sure how I got this. Is this the correct way to retrieve and download the file from a REST API call?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you just want to download the file and you don't have to worry about making rest-calls. You can do something like this (No external libraries are needed):

```
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.net.URI; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;
...
public void downloadFile(String url) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()) {
        Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)));
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
downloadFile("https://api.application.cap.cams.net/REST/sql_snapshot/2003-03-01.sql.gz")
```

Saves:

```
2003-03-01.sql.gz
```

This will save the file in the same directory as your project. If you want to place it in a specific place, you will have to modify `Paths.get(...)` and add your output-directory.

> *What happens here?*
>
> Get filename from URL: `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`.
>
> In order to download the file, you need to read it first. `InputStream`.
>
> Once you've read it by `URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()`.
>
> We save what we've read in our stream to disk using `Files.copy(...)`